# Cannot upload data through a foreign keys with Crispy Forms

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I display the values of categories and subcategories, getting the value from there and save it as a foreign key in the News entity.

> models.py

```
class News(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pic = models.ImageField()
    catid = models.ForeignKey(SubCat, on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING)

class Cat(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class SubCat(models.Model):   
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    catid = models.ForeignKey(Cat, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

> add_news.html

```
  <label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="example-text-input">Text Input</label>
  <div class="col-md-5">
       <input id="newstitle" name="newstitle" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-md-7">
  </div>

  <select id="newscat" name="newscat" class="select-chosen" data-placeholder="Choose a Category.." style="width: 250px;">
     {% for i in subcat %}
         <option value="{{ i.pk }}">{{ i.catid.name }} | {{ i.name }}</option>
     {% endfor %}
  </select>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVeKj.jpg)
Then I got all the values using queries and saved them like this:

> views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='mylogin')
def news_add(request):
    subCat = SubCat.objects.all()
     catID = request.POST['newscat']
     if request.method == 'POST':
             newstitle = request.POST['newstitle']                      
             newCatID = SubCat.objects.get(pk=catID)
             pic= request.FILES['picture']
             news = News(name=newstitle, catid=newCatID, pic=pic)
             ...
             news.save()
      else:
          return render(request, 'back/news_add.html', {'subcat' : subCat})
```

**But**, now how can I use the **crispy forms** to display the same list of categories with subcategories and save it in my model PK (catid)?

So, I can only display this

> add_news.html

```
<div class="col-md-5">
       {{ form.name|as_crispy_field }}
</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
       {{ form.pic|as_crispy_field }}
</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
       {{ form.catid.name|as_crispy_field }} {{ form.name|as_crispy_field }} # Not possible
</div>
```

> forms.py

```
class NewsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = News
        fields = ['name', 'pic', 'catid',]       
        labels = {'name': _('Title'),                  
                    'catid': _(''),
                    'pic': _('picture'),
                    }
```

> views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='mylogin')
def news_add(request):
    subCat = SubCat.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = NewsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():

            new = form.save()
            new.save()
            #form.save_m2m()

            return redirect('news_list')

    else:
        form = NewsForm()
        #newCatID = get_object_or_404(SubCat, pk = catID)

    return render(request, 'back/news_add.html', {'form':form, 'subcat' : subCat})
```

I described my problem as detailed as possible, because I’ve been thinking about it for several days

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding this correctly but it sounds like you are trying to display `SubCat`s in your form and save the selection from there?

Comment: Yeah! And save the primary key in the News.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it makes sense to just always display SubCat together with Cat:

```
class SubCat(models.Model):   
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    catid = models.ForeignKey(Cat, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} | {}".format(self.catid.name, self.name)
```